# Gap between two characters writing message over RS485

Tags: embedded, tty, serial-port, mono, stty

I am using an ATMEL embedded controller (at91sam9x25e) and its serial port to send/receive over RS485 Modbus RTU. Normal communication works fine, but sometimes - when writing - some packages are splitted with an delay from about 3.5ms between two characters within a message and are therefore detected as new message.

Settings:

- Mono 3.2.8
- Modbus RTU 19.2 kBaud
- RS485
- Auto-RTS

I am sending the whole package at once:

```
try  
{
  Thread.Sleep(_timePreSend);
  _serialPort.Write(buffer, offset, count);
} catch(Exception err)
{
   log.Error(err.Message);
} finally
{
   Thread.Sleep(2);
}
```

I used the 2 ms before, when I was Enabling/Disabling RTS manually, so that It transmitted the last bits from buffer (UART or FIFO).

Capture from oscillosope:

> 120318000100020032000403200000001C000500000000000000003D <- gap -> B6

[image: Modbus Message]

Output from stty:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS4 -a
speed 19200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;    
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl    -ixon  -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
 echoctl echoke
```

**What could be the reason for this gap? What can I do to avoid it?**

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say exactly what causes this. Unfortunately, Linux serial ports do not make timing guarantees, and normal UART protocols aren't supposed to have tight timing requirements like this. If your protocol requires this kind of timing guarantee, you're going to have to dig into your kernel drivers, and perhaps write your own driver that guarantees atomic delivery of all bytes with no gaps, probably using interrupts to ensure that the UART buffer is always refilled in a timely manner. You can't make this kind of guarantee from userspace without the kernel's help.

That said, you can try to figure out what causes your split, and, perhaps, work around it, and empirically determine that it's reliable enough in practice to work for your purposes. Is the delay always before the last byte? If so, it sounds like something in the stack is buffering a character for some reason, perhaps to optimize throughput by delivering multiple bytes to the hardware at once, and only delivering the lone byte after a small timeout. You should first ensure that your userspace app is behaving properly: check the system calls by running it under `strace` and make sure that the packet is written to the kernel in a single `write` system call. If it is, it's time to read the kernel source for your UART driver and see if there is any odd buffering involved.

Another possibility is that the kernel driver simply deals with the data in a kernel thread (or directly in your process context), and the gaps that you're seeing are another process getting scheduled. If so, the only way around this is to modify the kernel driver or write your own, so that it handles the transmission in a strict realtime manner without allowing other processes to take priority (e.g. doing everything in interrupt context).

Comment: Ok, thats bad news, that Linux doesnt guarantee timing. I already saw someone with a similar problem, but he didnt actually say what i did. See here:
I have never used strace before. Do you have any good reference(maybe in combination with serialport) where it is explained?
I will try to use system call for now, this already helped me out once and it seems to be a good idea!!
Writing own drivers should really be the absolut last option.
Thank you for your help meanwhile. I will write when I tested the system call and mabe strace ...

Comment: Linux isn't a real-time operating system (first and foremost); these days it does have real-time support, but for that to do what you want you need to carefully ensure that all components involved are designed to meet your real-time requirements. By default, assume anything you do can be interrupted at any time, for any length of time. It's a lot easier to guarantee real-time performance with a simpler OS. As for `strace`, just run `strace <your app>`. This will show all the system calls being made by your application. The `strace` manpage has a thorough explanation of how it works.

Comment: I used strace -T -p 2648 ....
I nearly only receive FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE and FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE messages but sometimes futex(0x3529d4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable). This is only received when I send to my embedded device (which is responsing as slave then). Could that futex_WAIT be the problem for the delay in the telegram?

Comment: I checked now, whether write and read happens from different threads, but they have same thread id.

Comment: You need to look for the `write()` call that writes the data. Use `strace -f` if your program is multithreaded to attach to all threads. You can use something like `-e trace=open,close,read,write` to trace a subset of syscalls; see the manpage for details. If the write writes the data all at once, the issue isn't in your userspace app.

Comment: I used the command: strace -p 3208 -f -e trace=write -tt -o write.log
What I see are the writes to my both interfaces. 
Sometimes I receive an <unfinished> and <... write resume tag> like here:

3212  02:18:23.121199 write(3, "h\201h\0\5\1\3\1\377\3", 10) = 10
3214  02:18:23.  write(6, "\1\3\n\0\0\0\0\1J\1J\1J\34\344", 15 <unfinished ...>
3212  02:18:23.208293 write(3, "h'h\0\20\1\16\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\17", 21 <unfinished ...>
3214  02:18:23.209327 <... write resumed> ) = 15
3212  02:18:23.209687 <... write resumed> ) = 21

Could that be the reason for my gaps?

Comment: Maybe. That just means that another thread called a system call while the write() was ongoing. As long as the write() has your entire packet of data (15 bytes and 21 bytes respectively in your example) then the problem isn't userspace buffering. If you're on a single-core system, having another thread get scheduled in the middle of the write() would support the theory that the kernel is pushing out bytes to the hardware in a preemptible context. You can try using a RT kernel (real-time build) and running your app with realtime priority (with `chrt`).

Comment: I tried to use a system call from libc with system function with the following string: /bin/bash -c "echo -e -n '\x01\x03\x02\x00\x00\xb8\x44' > /dev/ttyS4"

Comment: But it lead to the same problem of gaps. Can you conclude now, that is not a problem about the user space? I also dont know whether there is a RT kernel for this architecture and how to actually change it ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure echo would do the write in one syscall for a short string like that, so yes, you'll have to start looking into the kernel.

Comment: Thx marcan for you help it put me on the right track. Happily no kernel adaption is necessary. I finally found out the reason for the gaps ... look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was the issue for this behaviour. I used some busy waiting in my communication loop, which lead to heavy cpu load. I read then, that using SerialPort commands like **BytesToRead and Read** are not ideal at all:
[If you must use .NET System.IO.Port.Serialport](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)

Therefore I tried using asynchronous functions of ByteStream **ReadAsync and WriteAsync** as described in my new question [Proper way using timeouts with serial port and ReadAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744223/proper-way-using-timeouts-with-serial-port-and-readasync) and I have way less cpu usage and no gaps at all anymore.

Comment: Keep in mind that if your issue was CPU usage then that again points towards the kernel not doing serial writes in an uninterruptible interrupt context. Fixing the CPU usage issue will make it work most of the time, but not all of the time. Any other random CPU spike or latency issue will cause a gap, it will just be a rarer occurrence. So, if you're going to do it this way, you need to make sure you can tolerate the rare case of a gap happening anyway.